# Removing index.php from subdomain codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

I have looked on a few Stack Overflow questions for removing index.php from **sub domain** url please don't mark as duplicate.

**Stack Overflow I have Read And Tried.**

[CodeIgniter in subdomain folder, removing the index.php from address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447527/codeigniter-in-subdomain-folder-removing-the-index-php-from-address)

[remove index.php of codeigniter subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572628/remove-index-php-of-codeigniter-subdomains)

[Removing index.php and handling subdomains of two Codeigniter sites, when one within the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071203/removing-index-php-and-handling-subdomains-of-two-codeigniter-sites-when-one-wi)

But non seem to work I am using **WAMP** and **Codeigniter 3** and have MOD Rewrite enabled. Also I use virtual host.

> **Question:** What is the best suitable htacces for sub domain so that I can have the index.php remove?

**Page Error:**

```
codeigniter 500 internal server error
```

My Folder Structure is

```
www / 
www / codeigniter / cms-1 <-- This is main project
www / codeigniter / cms-1 / application

www / codeigniter / cms-1 / cms-2 <-- This is sub domain 
www / codeigniter / cms-1 / cms-2 / index.php
www / codeigniter / cms-1 / cms-2 / .htaccess

www / codeigniter / cms-1 / image / 
www / codeigniter / cms-1 / system 
www / codeigniter / cms-1 / .htaccess
www / codeigniter / cms-1 / index.php
```

When I have URL on WAMP like below does not work.

> `http://www.cms-2.cms-1.com/information/information/3`

But when I have index.php works.

> `http://www.cms-2.cms-1.com/index.php/information/information/3`

I have removed on the `application > config > config.php`

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

> This .htaccess below is on Main directory and works fine for main
>   domain.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: No luck goes Internal Server Error

Comment: Updated check this now

Comment: Thank you for your help I found out what was wrong. + 1

Comment: I used your htacces in the main directory now  and just have `RewriteBase /` working fine now. It works for both main and sub domain now.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your base_url

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on"){$ssl_set = "s";} else{$ssl_set = "";}
$config['base_url'] = 'http'.$ssl_set.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

In .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

For more read this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-make-multiple-websitesubdomain-of-your-main-site-in-codeigniter-with-same-code-and-database-dynamically/